# How can I power an LCD controller board with a power bank?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, lcd, powerbanks

I am new to electronics so need help.

I salvaged the screen of a broken [VivoBook E402NA](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Home/Everyday-use/VivoBook-E402NA/) laptop and bought [this controller](https://www.ebay.com/itm/184373677097) to turn it into an external monitor.

Evidently, this controller needs 12V DC and more than 3A as input power to work.

How can I provide this power using a normal ordinary power bank? If I'm not mistaken, the voltage provided by the power bank's USB is 5 volts, right? Can I convert it into 12 using a DC to DC converter? What will happen to its amperage then? Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: You can easily buy a one of SMPS power supply to power it.

Answer (score 1):

12V and 3A is 36 watts. You could use a step-up converter to convert 5V to 12V, but no normal ordinary power bank will give out 36 watts at 5V, that's 7.2 amps. Just connect it to mains powered power supply that can provide 12V and 3A.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Would you be able to take a look at this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2aY6cvk-WI&t=400s
It seems that the dude is using a power bank to power up the secondary monitor. But he doesn't talk about amps, so I'm a bit confused. Generally speaking, what will happen if the input power is, say, 12V but 1A instead of 3A?

Comment: that's a USB-PD power bank, not a 5v DC USB2.0 power bank like you describe. a PD one would work for you, probably, though 3A is still pushing it. If something wants 12V and 3A and your source provides 12V and 1A, it won't be 12V for long (micros).